# need to apply find method within the formula for all rows

Tags: vba, find, formula

I am using vlookup in my formula in  the macros . But it is taking too much time if it is applied for sheets containing more than 90k rows .

Instead i like to use find or Instr method  to reduce the time . But i am getting error if i use "find: method . I dont how to use "Instr"

```
Sub testt()

Dim l As Long

l = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Count
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("d1").Formula = "=IF(iferror(vlookup(c1,$D:$D,1,false),"""")="""","""",1)"
        .Range("d1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("d1:d" & l), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End Sub
```

here is my formula with vlookup . But i need to replace vlookup with find

```
l = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Count
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("d1").Formula = "=IF(iferror(range("A1:A" & l).find(c1),"""")="""","""",1)"
        .Range("d1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("d1:d" & l), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no FIND function in Excel that I know of.  However, you could write a VBA function to find each relevant cell in the lookup column.  Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
Function IfFound(SearchText As String) As String

Dim FoundCell As Range

'look in particular column for a value
Set FoundCell = Columns("A:A").Find(What:=SearchText, lookat:=xlWhole)

'if found, return value in cell to its right
If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    IfFound = ""
Else
    IfFound = FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
End If
```

End Function

Here's how you could call this:

```
Sub TestFunction()

'make sure word TEST is in column A somewhere
MsgBox IfFound("test")
```

End Sub

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it would run much more quickly than VLOOKUP.  The only problem is that you'd have to find a way to run it automatically whenever anything changed in the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks mate . Is it possible to make this statement as formulal like Range("d1").Formula = "=if(iferror(FoundCell = Columns("A:A").Find(What:=SearchText, lookat:=xlWhole),"""")="""","not found", found)

Comment: Simpler than that - you could write something like:

Range("D1").Value = IfFound("Whatever text you're looking for")

However, this will calculate slowly, because VBA functions are "volatile".  This means that Excel recalculates them every time you type anything into a cell (it has no concept of which functions can be ignored as being unaffected by the change just made), which defeats what you're trying to do!

Comment: Yes mate . i m trying to find a better way to do vlookup